# On Submit directly upload attachment to google drive using PHPRunner

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am creating a simple form using PHPRunner in which the attached file should directly be saved to Google Drive.
What expression should I put in the Upload Folder section?

Also I do want to rename the file when it is being uploaded.
After the upload, I need the URL of the file so that I can hyperlink the file and onClick of the link the file should be editable.

[image]

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.